# How to give a mob the player's motion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanna make a mob have the same Motion as a player
(as in changing their {Motion} tag)
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply overwrite the mob's motion to the player's, you deffinetly can. But this may not have the exact results you want.

```
/data modify entity <your mob target> Motion set from entity <your target player> Motion
```